# Print statement inside if loop not executing when CGI module is used

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, xampp

I'm writing a program which would fetch information from an HTML page using cgi and then pass the value to a for loop, the loop will search for the entry in an excel sheet and print the columns which matched the search criteria.

My Program looks like the one below, however it doesn't print the search results after every for loop, when the value is recieved using CGI, so "print(domain)" is not being executed.

```
#!c:\Python27\python.exe

import openpyxl
import cgi, cgitb

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "</body>"

formData=cgi.FieldStorage()
Mode=formData.getvalue('uniqvalue')
Mode_it={Mode}

wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('excelsheet.xlsx')
sheet= wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for rowNum in range (2, sheet.max_row):
    invName=sheet.cell(row=rowNum,column=2).value
    if invName in Mode_it:
         domain=sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value
         print(domain)

print "<h4> You searched for %s</h4>" % Mode

print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

The interesting part is if I do the following change and change the variable Mode and give a fixed value, it works perfectly.

basically, if I give the value as 7961 for the variable Mode it works:

```
formData=cgi.FieldStorage()
Mode=formData.getvalue('uniqvalue')
Mode_it={7961}
```

I know the loop works, and the last print statement prints the output of the value I entered in HTML so I know that works too.

I'm not sure why it doesn't when it's a variable. Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Example HTML I use has the following syntax:

```
<form action="Searchandreturn.py" method="post">
Enter the Value: <input type="text" name="uniqvalue"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: By default, all form values are strings.  Perhaps you want to convert `Mode` to an integer?  integer `7961` is not the same as string `'7961'`.

Comment: that's what I was missing, now I just have to figure out a function that will take a value such as 'atr193' and I should be good.  Thanks John.